# inotify Beacon on Oracle Linux using Salt

Tags: salt-stack, pyinotify, oraclelinux

I have a beacon working on OL 7.8 but when I try the same config on OL 7.7 it does not fire. I am not seeing anything in the minion logs when it starts, no errors on the beacon. Anything you can think of to check? The simple beacon:

```
  inotify:
    - files:
        /etc:
          mask:
            - modify
            - close_write
            - delete
            - attrib
          recurse: True
          auto_add: True
```

Comment: Is inotify actually installed?

Comment: Yes both servers are running pyinotify 0.9.6

Comment: If you can run a simple inotify example, just to ensure that inotify works on the box under that Python, that would at least rule that out.

Comment: Is it installed at the OS level on both? `yum install inotify-tools` ?